# Can I add more groupings to the top of the Inbox in Outlook?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

At the top of the Inbox, I have two (what appear to be) grouping categories. These show me either *All* e-mails in the folder or *Unread* e-mails. Can I add other categories into the space highlighted in red in the below image?

[image]

As an example, I'd like to add *Flagged* next to *Unread*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, I have done a lot of test and research but didn't find a method to achieve your requirement.

Considering that you need to display unread messages and flagged messages in separate places, as a workaround, it's suggested that you could create two search folders for Unread mails and flagged messages:

1.Right click **Search Folders**>click **New Search Folder…**

[image]

2.Create a search folder for **Unread mail** and **Mail flagged for follow up** respectively.
[image]

3.Just click the search folder to see the mail. (please note that the search folder only displays the results according to the search criteria, and the mail will still be in the original folder and will not be moved to this folder.)

[image]

Hope the above help!

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you have any further updates on this issue, please feel free to post back. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer. Warm thanks.